# Parcelable encountered IOException writing

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am implementing `Serializable` in POJO, when I minimize the android app then it throws following error
`E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object`
`Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractListRandomAccess`
Parent and Inner class both implemented `Serializable` but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your POJO class has `List` field which may or may not be `ArrayList`. Use `ArrayList` instead.